# 0-1 Knapsack 2 rows how to find elements

Tags: python, algorithm, knapsack-problem

Following the lesson [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/space-optimized-dp-solution-0-1-knapsack-problem/)

I've implemented a working 0-1 Knapsack algorithm only using two rows.

Which outputs the correct final value. 

Names contains the id of each element that is being used.

```
def KnapSack(val, wt, n, W): 
    names = n
    n = len(n)
    mat = [[0 for i in range(W + 1)] for i in range(2)] 

    i = 0
    while i < n: 
        j = 0 

        if i % 2 == 0: 
            while j < W:
                j += 1
                if wt[i] <= j:
                    mat[1][j] = max(val[i] + mat[0][j - wt[i]], mat[0][j]) 
                else:
                    mat[1][j] = mat[0][j] 
        else: 
            while j < W: 
                j += 1
                if wt[i] <= j: 
                    mat[0][j] = max(val[i] + mat[1][j - wt[i]], mat[1][j]) 
                else: 
                    mat[0][j] = mat[1][j] 
        i += 1
    if n % 2 == 0: 
        return mat[0][W] 
    else: 
        return mat[1][W]
```

Based on this code, how would I be able to output the elements used to create the correct knapsack value?

For example, the final output is 54, I need to find what elements added together get the value of 54.

Comment: mat will contain the final outcome of the knapsack, in my case 58. I'm trying to find the final elements that are added together to get to 58

Comment: I think I partially understand. In the new max function,I would store an array of the current elements used to generate the max value, but wouldn't the values stored begin to get duplicates after running the algorithm? Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: would you be able to provide pseudo-code for what the max function would be, I'm having difficulty understanding what you mean.

Comment: Save the solution values as a better max is found, overwriting the previous ones if the max is improved. When the best max is achieved and iteration ends, the current solution values will be either _one_ answer if there is more than one solution, or _the_ answer if there is a unique, global maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Just like with regular knapsack, you will have to track how you got to this particular state in your `DP` array. So in your `mat` table, instead of tracking the resulting sum, we are also going to track elements that constitute it - each entry in the table is now a tuple with the sum and list of names.

I also took a liberty of making one crucial refactoring in your code - do you see how similar `if` and `else` clauses of your code look? We can unite them by basing our logic around `i % 2` - in my code this is `cur`. This allows us to only write this logic ones - this is a fairly common trick for 0-1 knapsack. In general, you should avoid copy-pasting when possible, as it is often a source of errors. Without, further due, here's the code:

```
def KnapSack(val, wt, n, W): 
    names = n
    n = len(n)
    mat = [[(0, []) for i in range(W + 1)] for i in range(2)] 

    i = 0
    while i < n: 
        j = 0 
        cur = i % 2

        while j < W:
            j += 1
            if wt[i] <= j:
                if val[i] + mat[cur][j - wt[i]][0] > mat[cur][j][0]:
                    mat[1 - cur][j] = (val[i] + mat[cur][j - wt[i]][0], mat[cur][j - wt[i]][1][:] + [names[i]])
                else:
                    mat[1 - cur][j] = (mat[cur][j][0], mat[cur][j][1][:])
            else:
                mat[1 - cur][j] = (mat[cur][j][0], mat[cur][j][1][:]) 

        i += 1
    if n % 2 == 0: 
        return mat[0][W] 
    else: 
        return mat[1][W] 

print(KnapSack([7, 8, 4], [3, 8, 6], ['apple', 'box', 'peach'], 10))
```

prints `(11, ['apple', 'peach'])`, since 11 is the best value, made up of first and third elements.

Note the extra `[:]` to make copies of the list - lists aren't copied deeply, which would mess up our solution, as we would keep mutating the same list over and over.

Good luck in your studies!